# Multithreading in C# with Win.Forms control

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm beginner in C#. And i have problem with threads when i using win.forms. My application freezes. What the problem with this code? I'm using microsoft example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHInvalidOperation.WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true).
Here's my code:

```
    delegate void SetTextCallback(object text);

    private void WriteString(object text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the 
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread. 
        // If these threads are different, it returns true. 
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(WriteString);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = text.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread th_1 = new Thread(WriteString);
        Thread th_2 = new Thread(WriteString);
        Thread th_3 = new Thread(WriteString);
        Thread th_4 = new Thread(WriteString);

        th_1.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest; // самый высокий
        th_2.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal; // выше среднего
        th_3.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal; // средний
        th_4.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest; // низкий

        th_1.Start("1");
        th_2.Start("2");
        th_3.Start("3");
        th_4.Start("4");

        th_1.Join();
        th_2.Join();
        th_3.Join();
        th_4.Join();
    }
```

Comment: no exception, my form just freezes

Comment: Have you tried to debug your application to see where it is exactly getting hung up?

Comment: Well, that's nice to know! When does it freeze, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a deadlock - UI thread is waiting for threads to complete with `Thread.Join()` while the worker threads are trying to send a message to UI using blocking `Control.Invoke()`.  Replacing the Invoke in the thread code by BeginInvoke() will make the deadlock go away

```
 if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(WriteString);
        // BeginInvoke posts message to UI thread asyncronously
        this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text }); 
    }
    else
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: it's working but not how i expected, it's working fine when i add System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
in MyApp_Load. But i read that it's not recommended.

Comment: Try add System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false and in WriteString remove all and add textBox1.Text = text.ToString(); This is result what i expected but i read that it isn't recommended set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false

Comment: Sorry, I update my question and add for operator when i set textbox

Comment: It's different results when i set System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false and when i write like you told me

Answer (score 0):

It freezes because of the Join calls. Thread.Join() makes the current thread wait after another one is complete.

Comment: why it is not freezes if i add System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; in MyApp_Load?

Comment: @goodspeed - when you disable check you eliminate the deadlock since InvokeRequired returns false all the time.

Comment: exactly what alexm said. You can remove all you .Join() calls, since there is no logic in your code that would require to wait after all the threads to do something else.

Comment: i'm trying to understand why all is working fine when i add System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false